# Изменить возвращаемый по умолчанию тип функцией Ramda.is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, типы

Всем привет. Использую `Ramda.is` для проверки типов, однако столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Так, при проверке на массив `Ramda.is(Array)` возвращает тип `val is unknown[]`, в то время как мне необходим `val is any[]`. Есть ли способ изменить тип, используя, к примеру, дженерики. Или же единственный вариант использовать что-то наподобие `(val: any): val is any[] => R.is(Array)(val)`. Заранее спасибо за помощь)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `R.is(Array<any>, val)`

Comment: @nörbörnën Eslint подчеркиваеи и выдает `Parsing error: Expression expected.eslint`. Но спасибо за попытку)